# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" When making a small words list

Tags: python

I need to make a function using iteration to make a list of all words that are shorter than 3 letters. I keep getting some int error.

```
def shortWords(aList):
    total = 0
    aList = 0
    for index in aList:
        index = str(index)
        if len(aList([index])) <= 3:
           total = aList.append([index]) 
    return total

print(shortWords(['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Inigo', 'Montoya']))
```

Comment: `aList = 0` seems to destroy your list, it looks like irrelevant statement.

Answer (score 0):

You got `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` because you have declared `aList = 0` in your function, which overwrites the parameter that is passed into it.

It seems there is some confusion on how python loops work. When iterating through a list, it will return the value and not the index. So you can use it directly.

```
def shortWords(aList):
    words = [] # Declared to store any short words found
    for word in aList:
        if len(word) <= 3:
           words.append(word) # Short word found, appending to list
    return words # Return results

print(shortWords(['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Inigo', 'Montoya']))
# ['my', 'is']
```

Comment: Thank you! Why did you assign the words to the empty brackets? Also, why did you add the underscore between the short words?

Comment: whoops sorry, that was a mistake. That was just supposed to be `words`. The empty brackets (`words = []`) indicates a declaration of an empty list data type. Since the output was for a list of short words, the correct data type should be declared to contain it.

Comment: How do we know that "words" is assigned to the new list that needs to be appended?

Comment: I have modified the code snippet with comments to explain the flow

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a:

```
aList = 0
```

In the second line of the code!

Which overwrites the actual list.

So should remove it, then it will work, so would be:

```
def shortWords(aList):
    words = []
    for i in aList:
        if len(i) <= 3:
           words.append(i) 
    return words
```

Note that it `aList` doesn't contain the indexes, but the values already, remove few steps